# Create a "save as" dialog when user clicks button and subsequently download the file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

Basically all i need to know is how to create a generic "save as" menu, and then pass that information to my webclient filedownload method where it says "NEEDSTOBESAVEDAS. I already have an upload button in another area, and it saves the file's location on the server in a database, which is passed in the button click event. Here is my code:

```
--asp:linkbutton ButtonType="linkButton" Runat="server" Text="Download PDF" OnClick="Button2_Click" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("part_pdf") %>--

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim dlbutton As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
        Dim url = dlbutton.CommandArgument
        DownloadFile(url)
    End Sub

    Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _URL As String)

        Dim wclient As New WebClient()
        wclient.DownloadFile(_URL, "NEEDSTOBESAVEASDIALOG")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can not** have a custom *Save As* dialog client side.

Browser will **always prompt user to make a choice**, using file name (only, **without path**!) provided by server as default.

There is a very good reason for that: imagine if a web site may save a file to an arbitrary location without any user interaction:

- it may even overwrite user documents (and user won't even be aware of that)
- A malicious script what may overwrite system files or user data to execute arbitrary code (or to force user to do it).

In case (it's not so clear) you want to **select a folder from client side and then do download server side** (in a server folder) you'll hit another wall: usually (again for security reasons) IIS and ASP.NET users have **not enough privileges** to write stuff all around in the server (it's an open door for hackers).

Comment: so how do I make the browser ask?

Comment: @user3010161 You have at least two options: 1) point directly to file to be downloaded (using content-disposition to _force_ browser to download it instead of trying to open it). 2) use a proper download method, [see this example](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/08/downloading-any-file-to-the-browser-part-ii-using-asp-net/).

Comment: Thank you, I followed the second link and that utilizing that code got it downloading for me!

Comment: Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(_URL)
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & file.Name)
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString())
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName)
        Response.End()

Comment: ^ that was what was changed in the downloadfile method to get it running!

Comment: @user3010161 yes, WebClient.DownloadFile downloads file locally (on server). That's why I wasn't sure you were talking about a server side or client side download...

Comment: yea, there wasn't much on google about downloading files from the server; uploading was pretty easy to find though. In the future, I will need to add security measures (limit file size for one) to the uploading part. The downloading part only allows the user to download the file that was uploaded previously and associated with the part during part creation. Not only will I need to add security I will have to at least check for file type and ensure it's not overwriting another file. But anyway thank you for assistance have a happy thanksgiving!

Comment: You welcome, it's a good point you care about security! Have nice holidays